# How to share data between to components on each selected option change?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have two components, app.component and encours.component, I have a select in my app.component's navbar which need to send value to encours.component on each changing. I can get value the first time, but after, I can't get nothing. I have a service called dataService for the communication, and I use a router outlet for the routing, so I can't pass data from the router-outlet tag
I have tried to implement the ngOnChange method in encours.component, but it doesn't work.

Here is my service code :

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService{

  private serviceSource = new BehaviorSubject(3);
  currentService = this.serviceSource.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  changeService(service: number){
    this.serviceSource.next(service);
  }

}
```

Here is my app.component.html code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SAFRAN</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" *ngIf="showSelect">
      <select class="custom-select" id="service" #serviceSelect [(ngModel)]="service" name="service" (change)="setSelection(serviceSelect.value)">
        <option *ngFor = "let service of listeServices" value="{{service.id}}">{{service.nom}}</option>
      </select>
    </form>
</nav>

<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

Here is my app.component.ts code :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  public listeServices: any;
  service: number;

  constructor(private router:Router, private serviceServ : ServiceService, private data : DataService) {
    router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        //I get some data from an API
        this.getServices();
        //I show the select only if the route is encours
        this.showSelect = event.url === "/encours";
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data.currentService.subscribe(service => this.service = service)
  }

  public setSelection(selectedValue: any): void {
    this.service = selectedValue;
    this.data.changeService(selectedValue);
  }
```

Here encours.component.html file :

```
<table *ngIf="listeFamilles">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let f of listeFamilles">
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px;">{{ f.nom }}</th>
      <td  id="{{f.nom}}"  style="vertical-align: top;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And finally, my encours.component.ts :

```
export class EncoursComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{

  service : number;

  constructor(private serviceFam: FamillesService, private serviceOpe: OperationsService, private serviceVar: VarianteService, private serviceAff: AffaireService, private serviceAffecter: AffecterService, private data : DataService) {
    this.data.currentService.subscribe(service => this.service = service);
  }

  //This function is never called
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
  }
```

Comment: You should post the code to your template because your problem is not reproducible without it

Comment: @Jamie it's done

Comment: Ok, I now understand the problem better. Are you specifically wanting `ngOnChanges()` to fire or do you only care about when the value of `currentService` in the **DataService** changes?

Comment: I would like to refresh my encours.component.ts at each changing, with the new value in service of EnCoursComponent

Comment: the subscription you have in **encours.component.ts** will be called whenever that value changes. Change the subscription line in the constructor to console log this update `this.data.currentService.subscribe(service => cosole.log(service));` and you should be able to see this, yes?

Comment: Yes thank you it works now !! But how does the constructor be called numerous time?

Comment: And how can I get the changing on the ngOnChange method ?

Comment: The constructor is not getting called multiple times, simply only the function that is declared as a parameter of the subscription. `service => console.log(service)` is actually a function that can be read like `function(service: any) { console.log(service) }` & is the only thing being called multiple times, not the constructor. Implementing `ngOnChange` would be verbose for this use case. But, an example of implementing this can be found here: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-onchanges-simplechanges-example. Official documentation here: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges.

Comment: i will post this chain as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscription you have in **encours.component.ts** to the **DataService**'s `data` field will be called whenever that value changes so this component actually is already receiving this data. Implementing the interface `ngOnChanges` would be verbose for a use case like this as the component is already receiving the updated value in the subscription you have in the constructor.

Change the subscription line in the constructor to console log this update:

```
this.data.currentService.subscribe(service => {
    console.log(service);
    this.service = service;
});
```

and now are be able to see that this is actually already the case.

Extra work is required if you want to (in my opinion, verbosely) fire `onChanges()` and handle the updates there. `onChanges()` only fires when an property with an `@Input` attribute changes. This would require you to pass the value of the **DataService**'s `currentService` as an `@Input` through the template which is achievable via **async pipe**.

An example of implementing this can be found here: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-onchanges-simplechanges-example. Official documentation here: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This function is never called
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
  }
```

Of course, ngOnChanges hook is called when any data-bound property changes,
So if It would only work if the component **EncoursComponent** would have a **@Input** property.

Comment: yes I know, but even if I declare service like that :
    @Input() service : number;

The function is never called

Comment: function its only called when change the reference of an @input property